# UILabel is not updating with value from another class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm a beginner iPhone developer.

I have 2 classes. `TestViewController` (this is linked withe view in the storyboard) and `ViewController`.

I am trying to call a method(`[tc refresh:val];`) in `TestViewController` with `val` as the parameter from `ViewController` class. I can see from the logs that `val` reaches the `TestViewController`, but for some reason, the label does not update and I do not get the current text of the label also which I have set in the view. It gives `null` value. Please see the code and log i get and advice me how can I get the label updated by calling a method from `VC` to `TVC`.

### TestViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblDisp;

- (IBAction)chngText:(id)sender;
- (void)refresh:(NSString *)val;

@end
```

### TestViewController.m

```
#import "TestViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation TestViewController
@synthesize lblDisp;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"TEST VC LOADED");
    NSLog(@"TEXT CUrret VALUE SUPERVIEW %@",lblDisp.text);
}

- (IBAction)chngText:(id)sender {
    ViewController *dd=[[ViewController alloc]init];
    [dd display];
}

-(void)refresh:(NSString *)val{
    NSLog(@"Value of Val = %@",val);
    NSLog(@"TEXT CUrret VALUE %@",lblDisp.text);
    lblDisp.text=val;
}
@end
```

### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

-(void)display;

@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TestViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"VC LOADED");
}

-(void)display{
    NSLog(@"Reached VC");
   NSString *val=@"1";
    TestViewController *tc=[[TestViewController alloc]init];
    [tc refresh:val];
}

@end
```

### Log

```
2013-07-24 03:13:36.413 Simple test[38477:11303] TEST VC LOADED
2013-07-24 03:13:36.415 Simple test[38477:11303] TEXT CUrret VALUE SUPERVIEW sdfgdfgd
2013-07-24 03:13:37.909 Simple test[38477:11303] Reached VC
2013-07-24 03:13:37.910 Simple test[38477:11303] Value of Val = 1
2013-07-24 03:13:37.911 Simple test[38477:11303] TEXT CUrret VALUE (null)
```

Comment: lblDisp.text=val;NSLog(@"TEXT CUrret VALUE %@",lblDisp.text);   edit these two lines in your code

Comment: are u calling display method from TestViewController's changetxt method ?

Comment: @TapanNathvani edit it to what?It doesnt show the current value which is "sdfgdfgd"

Comment: in your refresh method

Comment: can you tell the flow of the application?It is really confusing . `Appdelegate-> TestViewController-> ViewController`?is this the flow

Comment: @TapanNathvani If u meant to edit the code by changing the order of those 2 lines i changed and i still get null as the value.

Comment: @LithuT.V TestViewController - >ViewController -> TestViewController.

Comment: @LithuT.V It did not work. It still gave null value

Comment: at the end, to do that ,, you need to use NSNotification

Comment: you are not passing the data to the original instance which u created initially. instead u are passing the data by creating a new instance of the TestViewController. So you are getting nil...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in the way you pass the value back.

```
TestViewController *tc=[[TestViewController alloc]init];
[tc refresh:val];
```

The first line creates and initializes a new instance `tc` of your `TestViewController` Class. This allows you to access its methods, but that doesn't mean you're accessing the instance you created initially or the data you originally assigned. This means your label `lblDisp`, along with the rest of your new `TestViewController` instance's properties, are nil.

Basically you can't use this strategy to pass data back and forth. See this SO post:

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is pretty simple

```
  -(void)refresh:(NSString *)val{
        NSLog(@"Value of Val = %@",val);
        NSLog(@"TEXT CUrret VALUE %@",lblDisp.text);
        lblDisp.text=val;
    }
```

here after the log is printed, value is updated so change the code like this order in which label is updated first and then log the value

So use

```
  -(void)refresh:(NSString *)val{
        lblDisp.text=val;
        NSLog(@"Value of Val = %@",val);
        NSLog(@"TEXT CUrret VALUE %@",lblDisp.text);
    }
```

**EDIT**

Well the reason may be the `lblDisp` is loaded from nib and it is not a valid memory till the view is presented/pushed .And then only the method will have valid label instance and then only you can update it